# ハイブリッドアプリで、端末ごと（iOS、android）で生じてしまうアニメーションの動きを改善する良い方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, ios, android, monaca, jquery

プログラミング初心者です。
現在、「Monaca」を使ってアプリを開発しています。

カードを裏返すアニメーションを組んでいるのですが、
デバッガーで確認したところ、iOS端末とandroid端末で
動作に違いが出てしまいます。

使用している端末は、
iOS：iPhone5
android:GalaxyS5(SC-04F)、Nexus7(ME571)
です。

iOS端末での動きは問題ないのですが、
android端末のNexus7での動きがやや重くなる印象です。
ちなみに、Nexus7にインストールされている「AndroidシステムのWebView」のアップデートはされています。

改善する良い方法、アプローチの仕方等ありましたら、教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: CrossWalkはWebレンダリングエンジンを統一するので良い方法かと思いますが、現状では実装されているコードが不明なためボトルネックが分かりません。またCrossWalkはメリットもありますがデメリットもあります。レンダリングエンジンを切り替える前にボトルネックを調査するのが先ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
自分でも、はっきりと問題の切り分けができていない状況で質問してしまいました。
アドバイス頂いたとおり、まずはボトルネックの調査から初めてみます。

Comment: 論点はボトルネックではなく実装されているコードやサンプル、参考にした資料等が無いので回答しづらいと言いたかったのですが……。もちろん切り分けが出来ていれば回答もスムーズに済むので出来ていれば良いとは思います。

Answer (score 2):

AndroidはバージョンによってWebViewが大きく異なります。

・〜4.3まではAndroid固有のブラウザベースでのWebView
・4.4.xはChromiumベースのWebView
・5.x〜はAndroid OSから切り離して、Google Play経由でのアップデートが可能
(Chromiumベースなのは同じ)

もし、Android4.xもアプリの対象に入っているのであれば、Crosswalkを使ってみてはいかがでしょうか？

Crosswalkは自身のプロジェクトにライブラリとしてWebViewエンジンごと組み込むので、全てのAndroid OSで同じWebViewを使うことができます。

Monacaでも利用できるようですよ。
http://blog.asial.co.jp/1371

少しでも助けになれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
実際に試してみたところ、残念ながら改善されませんでした。
しかし、Crosswalkについて知ることができて勉強になりました。
再度、自分のコードを見返して、問題の切り分けからしっかりやり直したいと思います。